# How can I get a video URL list (e.g. YouTube playlist) as a playlist file (for media players)?

Tags: video, conversion, file-format, playlists

Following these steps has gotten me almost all the way:

- I can get a text file of YouTube URLs from a YouTube playlist by using this https://thetubelab.com/get-all-urls-of-youtube-playlist-channel/ site.
- I can encode the raw url list into a `.xspf` file with a Notepad++ macro to wrap each url with `<track><location>http://[insert url]<location></track>`, along with some easy additional XML data manually inserted.
- I am able to play this `.xspf` file in VLC, but there are no previews, nor filters for broken URLs.
- I can manually play each video in the list, which will load the preview data. I can then save the updated (and now-verbose) playlist to a new file.

Problem is, that last step will take an enormous amount of time, and I don't know of a way to automate it quickly. Is there an easy way to do this without writing a custom VLC lua script or something?

**Update:** I found [this site](https://ytplaylist-len.us/youtube-playlist-link-extractor.html), which allows for extracting song titles along with the urls. I'm still working out how to get them into the playlist format, though.

Comment: Does it have to be XSPF? Or can it be e.g. M3U?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what playlist file format. I just used XSPF because it was easier to macro process the URLs for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea for you - use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) in a way or another.

For example, this command:

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpeFO20OwBF4q8wyEukQxs5h_ktfIvpcG --skip-download --no-warning --print "#EXTIMG:%(thumbnail)s" --print webpage_url
```

will output all the YT video thumbnail URLs followed by new line and video URLs. It'll skip unavailable/inaccessible videos.

Then you could rework that to print into e.g. [extended M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#Extended_M3U) format instead. First, print the header  to a new file:

```
echo #EXTM3U > playlist.m3u
```

Afterwards use similar appending redirection (`>>`) in the yt-dlp command mentioned above.

Few notes:

- extended M3U is not widely supported, although many modern players at least partially support it
- `#EXTIMG` with URL might not be an available option in various players on top of that
- different formats of thumbnails might also not work, e.g. you can get default `.webp` thumbnail using the above command. You could try to further work around that by requesting a more specific format like `.jpg` from printable `thumbnails_table` property. Or you could go for JSON processing with `--flat-playlist` and `--dump-single-json` options instead, but that will require another program, like [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq).
- the command may have unintended results with hidden/deleted videos

Comment: VLC allows saving playlists in different formats, so I'm not worried about m3u.